# I am applying Princomp function on kddcup99.

Tags: matlab, pca

I am applying Princomp function on kddcup99 after removing attributes which are string, dataset but result of it is a matrix of dimension (37 X 37), the resulted matrix is very low in dimension than original ,could i can use it as training sample for anomaly based intrusion detection system.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the dataset and you haven't really specified a machine learning method, so my answer would be maybe. The best way to know is to plot your dataset, maybe even try applying an SVM, DT, Naive Bayes, or kmeans.

Now I presume you're not using princomp properly if your feature vector is 37 dimensions. I'm also assuming that your other 37 comes from the size of your training set. Did you plot a Scree plot and truncate your coefficient matrix? IIRC princomp() should have a similar functionality as pca().
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html

Please post your code for me to help further.